# Collision with images

Tags: python, pygame

I have to do a game in 2d using pygame and I don't know how to detect collisions with images

I have tested the collisions with rectangles and it works, but when I try to collide a rectangle with an image, the application crash

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint

pygame.init()
ventana=pygame.display.set_mode((1200,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Jueguiño")

imageVida= pygame.image.load("vida.jpg")
posX= randint(0,1200)
posY= randint(0,0)

rectangulo=pygame.Rect(0,0,100,50)


velocidad=0.5

Blanco=(255,255,255)

while True:
    ventana.fill(Blanco)
    ventana.blit(imageVida,(posX,posY))
    pygame.draw.rect(ventana,(180,70,70),rectangulo)

    rectangulo.left,rectangulo.top=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if rectangulo.colliderect(imageVida):
        velocidad=0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    if posY<1200:
        posY+=velocidad
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyGame is does not collide-test images with rectangles, it collides rectangles with rectangles.  So the code needs to track the position of the image as-if it *is a rectangle*.

This is quite easy.  Initially get the rectangular-shape of the image with `.get_rect()`, this gives the code a PyGame `rect` object.  Then the code needs only move and collide the rectangle, but also must ensure the image is always painted at the rectangle's co-ordinates to keep everything synchronised.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint

pygame.init()
ventana=pygame.display.set_mode((1200,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Jueguiño")

imageVida= pygame.image.load("vida.jpg")
vidaRect = imageVida.get_rect()            # <-- Get the Image's Rectangle
posX= randint(0,1200)
posY= randint(0,0)
vidaRect.center = ( posX, posY )           # <-- Position the Rectangle

rectangulo=pygame.Rect(0,0,100,50)

velocidad=0.5

Blanco=(255,255,255)

while True:
    ventana.fill(Blanco)
    ventana.blit( imageVida, ( vidaRect.x, vidaRect.y ) )  # <-- Draw at the Rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(ventana,(180,70,70),rectangulo)

    rectangulo.left,rectangulo.top=pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if rectangulo.colliderect( vidaRect ):  # <-- Collide-test the Rectangle
        velocidad=0
        print("Collision!")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    if posY<1200:
        posY+=velocidad
    pygame.display.update()
```

It's probably valuable to read the documentation on the PyGame [Sprite Class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).  It is a complete set of functions for handling exactly this sort of work.  It is a little more complicated at first, but then simplifies a great deal of the later work - like colliding groups of sprites, for example.  There are numerous examples of using sprites in the PyGame answers on SO.

Comment: Nice, it works but now the objects doesnt collides on the screen and for the system they collides

Comment: Your collision code is using `rectangulo.left`, `rectangulo.top` - maybe this needs to be (X,Y) or suchlike.

Comment: i can fix it, the speed is the problem, it was at 0.5, i put it at 1 and the rectangles collides as they should, thanks for everything :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to collide with the image directly. Instead, use the `.get_rect()` function to get a rectangle for the image that you can check for collisions with.

[Pygame docs for .get_rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect).